# Prevent postback if particular value is selected in dropdown

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, html-select

I have a drop down with Autopostback property true, I want, If select `Select Week` option then it should not postback else it should post back. Below are the function.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function OnWeekChange() {
        var value = $("#DropDownListWeeks option:selected").val();
        if (value == "-1")
         return false; 
        else return true;
    }
```

ASPX

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListWeeks" runat="server" Height="23px" Width="252px"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListWeeks_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="true"  onchange="return OnWeekChange();"> 
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

.CS

```
 weeks = client.GetWeeks(true);
        foreach (Roaster_Week week in weeks)
        {
            //Add weeks in the dropdowns with formatting 
            DropDownListWeeks.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Format("{0:MMM d, yyyy}", week.StartDate) + " - " + string.Format("{0:MMM d, yyyy}", week.EndDate),week.WeekID.ToString()));
        }
        client.Close();
        DropDownListWeeks.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Week","-1"));
```

Here in my case post back is not happening at all even when I select value other than `-1` .When I tried with `Jquery` *it postbacks* for all the values, why such behavior occur?
Can you please provide the appropriate solution for my scenario.

Comment: try to put alert inside the function and check weather the function is working or not

Comment: control is going in OnWeekChange() function reaches `else return true;` part but does not make postback

Comment: what happens when you remove `onchange` event. does it works?

Comment: Yes. It is working fine in that case.

Comment: I have put one answer kindly use that it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having similar problem however i solved using this code.it has worked for me.

```
function OnWeekChange() {
            var value = $("#DropDownListWeeks option:selected").val();
            if (value == "-1")
             return false; 
            else {
             __doPostBack(value , '');
            }
         }




<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListWeeks" runat="server" Height="23px" Width="252px"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListWeeks_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static"
                        AppendDataBoundItems="true"  onchange="return OnWeekChange();"> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Yes it works for me. But I think that is not a practice to use it. It may violets the benefits from the normal postback from dropdown..

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onchange="return OnWeekChange();"` and add the function below it will work.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DropDownListWeeks").change(function () {
            var value = $("#DropDownListWeeks option:selected").val();
            alert(value);
            if (value == "-1")
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        });
    });
```